# SweetAlert Content input required to click confirm?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
swal({
        title   : "Um produto escolhido não foi o mais barato!",
        text    : "Para continuar será necessário informar uma 
                 justificativa, desejá continuar? \n\nProdutos:",
        icon    : "warning",
        buttons : {  
            cancel  : "Cancelar",
            confirm : "Confirmar",
        },
        content : {
            element    : "input",
            attributes : {
                placeholder : "Informe a justificativa...",
                type        : "text",
            },
        },
        closeOnClickOutside : false,
        closeOnEsc          : false,
})
.then((value) => {

});
```

How to put content: {element: "input"}, as a required field, when clicking confirm?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```js
swal({
    title: 'Edit Variable',
    input: 'text',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Update',
    preConfirm: function (email) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (email === '') {
                    alert("err");
                    reject('err')
                } else {
                    resolve()
                }
            }, 1000)
        })
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.3.4/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.11.0/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.11.0/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Check this example

Comment: I tried it however it did not work when I click on confirm even with the empty input it continues and closes the modal

Comment: which sweetalert2 to this one I use https://sweetalert.js.org/ could you tell me?

Comment: i am using sweetalert2 you can find the imported script above.